# Understanding the flow of spring framework & MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having some trouble understanding this. Can someone help me better understand this?

```
MVC 
Model --> Java- Spring Framework
View ---> templating language(JSP velocity) & Javascript 
DB --> SQL
```

Q-1)
Now, When I open a particular page, I can't visualize the flow. I've read about DAO, controller , service etc and I understand them individually but I am really confused when I club all together what's the order of execution? Whats the flow exactly ? Is it that  first the view is loaded then it sends JS request to fetch the necessary data from backend and then the controller and service are invoked and the DAO queries the db? Then how does the API come into picture? DAO deals with the API?

Q-2)
Why do we need xyz.properties? I have removed a module from my page. If I remove a particular js file(related to that module) from the scripts.properties, then ideally that js should not get executed at all right? Then still why would I see the api call to fetch the data related to that module? I don't see the module but I sure see the api call. Why is that?

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for. If you're running a client-side framework that makes all the requests, then the request comes from the browser, hits a controller, which might hit the DB, and it renders results back to the requester.

Answer (score 4):

DB doesn't enter in MVC model. And you're forgetting a principal element in your analysis: the **Controller**. The flow goes like this:

- Client performs a request to an URL
- The application server gets the URL and *passes* the handling to the web application.
- The web application using Spring MVC will handle the URL processing to the Controller: `DispatchServlet`, which is a Servlet.
- The `DispatchServlet` will try handle the URL. If there's an URL mapping, then it will pass it to the class (mapped in the spring.xml config or decorated with `@Controller` annotation).
- This *controller* (which in fact is part of the model) will handle the request. It will call services, daos, etc (Model) and return the necessary data to complete the response to the `DispatchServlet`.
- The `DispatchServlet` will finish the request handling and, in the end, will generate the results e.g. a text/json response, or it will forward to a JSP file (View).

For question two, I **never** have used such scripts.properties file, so I don't know what you're talking about. Usage of a properties file is to store application properties that should not change until an application redeploy. They have 3 main advantages:

1. They can be easily manipulated by human users. It's no rocket science to add, edit or remove values.
2. Since it is a plain text, it's easier to version using a version control system like SVN, Git or another of your preference.
3. It provides a faster access since it is usually in the same disk as the application, so there's no much time penalty when accessing to its contents compared to a database configuration. But since it is in disk, it still has a disadvantage against RAM access only.

Comment: so property file is just like an index but it does not really play an imp role right?

Comment: @user3841595 no, they don't. You can create an entire application w/o using a properties file, but I doubt about a real world decent application that doesn't have any property at all.

Comment: @user3841595 I don't understand. Please provide more details. If you're talking about Hibernate or Spring JDBC, ask about it. If you have your own framework based on plain JDBC to access to your database, then ask your teammates about it. If you're asking about the specific jar to connect to the database like MySQL or Postgres or Oracle, then ask about the exact library-database engine combination. API is a very generic term.

Comment: My Question is that if its our own framework based on plain JDBC to access our database then does the DAO do that processing generally? Thanks for the answers btw

Comment: @user3841595 DAO is just acronym for Data Access Object. If the class has the responsibility to access to a data source, then is a DAO. As simple as that. And for your specific question, the DAO classes should use your own framework to access to your database.

Comment: okay.got you. So if I have to remove an api call, I'll have to remove that from the DAO. thats right?

Comment: @user3841595 perform some tests based on your new experiences and you will find the answer.

Comment: yeah. I tried taking off the implemented methods in the DAO which make the API call but it din't really do it. I'm afraid of alterin it as the application is huge and has many dependencies. So wnated to know if I'm looking at te correct place.

Comment: @user3841595 create a simple toy project where you can make such changes. The best way to learn programming/software architecture/how software works is not just by reading but by practicing and applying the infamous scientific method: [trial and error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_and_error).

Answer (score 0):

In simple layman's term, MVC explained in pictorial form

```
    (inputing data)    (data related part)   (display rendering)
   -request mapping      -classes            -JSP (Script,CSS,HTML)
   -request param        -interface           -velocity  
     Controller ------------->Model--------------->View
                               ||
                               \/
            (data processing logic)    (access to Databse)
              -optimization                -JDBC
              -business logic              -SQL
                 Service--------------------->DAO
```